# Differents between Ext.create and new Class?

Tags: javascript, extjs

What's  Differents between Ext.create and new Class ?

```
 Ext.define('className_root',{ members:'many',age:19}, function(){
  console.log( ' Callbackstarted after class created' )
});


var eugene = Ext.create('className_root');

var other = new className_root;


console.log(other == eugene); //false
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the ExtJS setup, if [Ext.Loader](http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-ext-loader-for-your-application/) is enabled then Ext.create will attempt to load the class if it hasn't been defined yet. The `new` keyword will fail if the class is not defined.

Also, your comparison will return false regardless of how your two objects are created. `eugene` and `other` are created as two entirely separate objects in memory. You'd want to do something more like:

```
typeof(eugene) == typeof(other)
```